# How to refresh a widget on the outside?

Tags: flutter, dart

There is a red customView and a button in the page:

[image]

I want to change the customView's color to green when I tap the button.

**Require:**

1. You must call customView's function `changeColor` to achieve it;
2. You can't call page's `setState`, it's stateless;
3. Do not use eventBus or provider.

Here is all my code, you can copy and test, input your code in `CustomView`'s `changeColor`, I desire the easiest way.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class RefreshOutsidePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const RefreshOutsidePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CustomView customView = CustomView();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('refresh outside')),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          customView,
          SizedBox(height: 30),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text('refresh outside'),
            onPressed: () {
              customView.changeColor();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomView extends StatefulWidget {
  CustomView({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CustomViewState createState() => _CustomViewState();

  void changeColor() {
    // input your code here
    print('change');
  }
}

class _CustomViewState extends State<CustomView> {
  Color color = Colors.red;

  void changeColor() {
    setState(() {
      color = Colors.green;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 200,
      height: 200,
      color: color,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change it through `key`:

1. Make CustomViewState `public` (remove _ at beginning)
2. Define `key` and call function `changeColor`:

```
class RefreshOutsidePage extends StatelessWidget {
  
  const RefreshOutsidePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  final _customViewKey = GlobalKey<CustomViewState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('refresh outside')),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          CustomView(key: _customViewKey),
          SizedBox(height: 30),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text('refresh outside'),
            onPressed: () {
              _customViewKey.currentState.changeColor();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two main solutions.

- `Key` solution as mentioned by [Autocrab](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68128929/14559140).
- `State` solution where the parent widget becomes `Stateful` or implement any state management solution in Flutter to update the values of his child.

The child `CustomView` should be `Stateless` as it is now because you are **not changing the state within widget**. So you just require extra parameters received from the parent widget to properly update or get a reference to the widget with the `GlobalKey` to update it.

If you are using this project for learning or something not legacy I suggest you upgrade Flutter as `RaisedButton` is deprecated and on the long term you will also have to use null-safety. But that is outside the scope of this question.